# Syncing Core Data with server response

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, afnetworking

I'm not sure how to deal with problem which has occured to me.

I have a app which is using `AFNetworking` to get `JSON` from server which I put into `SQLite` using `Core Data`. But every time I launch an app I have to chceck if there are some new objects on server and sync them with local ones on device. **How to deal with this sync between server and app?**

One way is to clear the whole database and download everything once again but I have one attribute which is holding state of the object (**selected**) and I can't lose this information. I was given an advice to sync the response with current database but I really have no idea how to do this efficiently and in smart way.

My only idea is to fetch everything, and compare each object from response with whole `NSArray`. If there is match then break loop and if there isn't add object.

I'm using this method to get everything from server and put it to database:

```
[[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] GET:ALL_GROUPS parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    for (id group in responseObject) {
        Group *groupEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Group" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];

        groupEntity.name = [group valueForKey:@"name"];
        groupEntity.cashID = [group valueForKey:@"id"];
        groupEntity.caseInsensitiveName = [[group valueForKey:@"name"] lowercaseString];
        groupEntity.selected = FALSE;

        NSError *error;
        if (![self.moc save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // Show alert with info about internet connection
    UIAlertView *internetAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ups!" message:@"Wygląda na to, że nie masz połączenia z internetem" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [internetAlert show];
}];
```

And this little guy to fetch everything:

```
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Group" 
                                              inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

I would appreciate any suggestion... I'm stuck with this one...

Comment: Can the data downloaded to device be changed by user?

Comment: @CarmeloS, only `selected` attribute can.

Comment: Ther's an implementation of NSIncrementalStore by AFHTTPNetworking, you can also look on it: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though @Rich solution is correct, it is O(N*M) complexity solution.
N is the total number of groups in the database
M is the number of groups recieved in the response

You success code could be:

```
NSMutableDictionary* groups = [NSMutableDictionary new];
NSMutableArray* newIds = [NSMutableArray new];
for (id group in responseObject) {
    Group *groupEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Group" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];

    groupEntity.name = [group valueForKey:@"name"];
    groupEntity.cashID = [group valueForKey:@"id"];
    groupEntity.caseInsensitiveName = [[group valueForKey:@"name"] lowercaseString];
    groupEntity.selected = NO;
    groups[groupEntity.cashID] = groupEntity;
    [newIds addObject:groupEntity.cashID];
}

NSFetchRequest* r = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Group"];
[r setIncludesPendingChanges:NO];
r.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cashID IN %@",newIds];
NSArray *existingGroups = [self.moc executeFetchRequest:r error:&error];

for (Group* g in existingGroups) {
    Group* newGroup = groups[g.cashID];
    g.name = [newGroup valueForKey:@"name"];
    g.cashID = [newGroup valueForKey:@"cashID"];
    g.caseInsensitiveName = [[newGroup valueForKey:@"name"] lowercaseString];
    [self.moc deleteObject:newGroup];
}

// Save any changes
NSError *error;
if (![self.moc save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Which is O(M) complexity

Comment: Yeah, I was just giving him an idea to get on with!
A note on yours though, you don't need an array to store the `newIds` AND a dictionary to store the new groups, you can just use the `allKeys` method of the dictionary.
But more importantly your predicate is wrong, it needs to be `cashID IN %@` :)

Comment: @Rich, thanks, I've corrected the predicate. the array is there to avoid making another pass over the objects (another O(M) operation)

Comment: @DanShelly I have one problem with your code. When I'm running this for the first time it isn't saving anything... An probably `newGroup` should be declared as a `Group*`.

Comment: @DanShelly now everything works fine. `[r setIncludesPendingChanges:NO];`was missing :)

Answer (score 1):

If your main target is reducing net transmission and faster syncing, I would recommend that you change the server to a versioned data structure, when the user load data from server, you first upload the version number you have on your device, then the server compare the newest version with the version on device, decide which data that already on the device is changed, and which data is missing on the device, transfer only these data to device, it will make your syncing faster if most data stays the same between device and server.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right lines with fetching the current data and then comparing against the new data.
The simplest way is a loop inside the loop:

```
-(void)makeRequest
{
    [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] GET:ALL_GROUPS parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [self addNewObjects:responseObject];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        // Show alert with info about internet connection
        UIAlertView *internetAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Ups!" message:@"Wygląda na to, że nie masz połączenia z internetem" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [internetAlert show];
    }];
}

-(void)addNewObjects:(NSArray *)groups
{
    // Get the current groups
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Group" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *currentGroups = [self.moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

    for (id group in groups) {

        id groupID = [group valueForKey:@"id"];

        Group *currentlySavedGroup = nil;

        // Look for a current object
        for (Group *groupEntity in currentGroups) {
            if ([groupEntity.cashID isEqualTo:groupID]) {
                // We've found a current object so finish looking
                currentlySavedGroup = groupEntity;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!currentlySavedGroup) {
            // Create a new one
            Group *currentlySavedGroup = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Group" inManagedObjectContext:self.moc];
            currentlySavedGroup.selected = NO;
        }

        // Update regardless of saved or not
        currentlySavedGroup.name = [group valueForKey:@"name"];
        currentlySavedGroup.cashID = [group valueForKey:@"id"];
        currentlySavedGroup.caseInsensitiveName = [[group valueForKey:@"name"] lowercaseString];
    }

    // Save any changes
    NSError *error;
    if (![self.moc save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```